# Remove CSV formula values during mysql load data infile import

Tags: python, mysql, regex, csv, load-data-infile

So I'm trying import a .csv file directly into mysql using `load data local infile` command but I'm running into fields that are remnants an excel formula field and I don't know how to get rid of them.  The content for the first field in the example below has an `=` in front of it.

The table structure is setup to allow the first field to be a `VARCHAR(100)` but I'd like to make it an `INT` if possible.  Here is a sample of the csv content that is being uploaded.

```
"MID","DBA Name","Partner ID","Partner Name","Sub Partner ID","Sub Partner Name","Active Months","Bonus Amount","Bonus Applied Date","Partner Percentage","Partner Share","Total Payment"
="0008788014065741","company2","7968","me,"11839","Joe Blow","0","$50.00","","","","$350.64"
="0008788014065756","company2","7968","you","11839","Joe Blow","0","$50.00","","","","$294.60"
```

And here is the mysql load command that I'm using to import the data:

```
sql = """
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%(upload)s' IGNORE INTO TABLE `%(table)s`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES ;
      """ % {"upload": file, "table": report}
self.db.query( sql )
```

Is there something that can be done on the import in terms of a regex or something? I don't know, I'm just grasping at straws here...

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Do all lines in your file starts with `=`?

Comment: in this particular file it looks like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it two ways with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

**First** read first field values as is and then strip equal sign `=` and double quotes from it in `SET` clause. Also you most likely want to do other transformations while you're loading data like:

- set actual `NULL`s when your fields are empty
- strip dollar signs from monetary values
- you probably have to transform date values (but your sample data doesn't have them so there is no information to deduce from)

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE table_name
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@MID, DBAName, PartnerID, PartnerName, SubPartnerID, SubPartnerName, ActiveMonths,
 @BonusAmount, @BonusAppliedDate, @PartnerPercentage, @PartnerShare, @TotalPayment)
SET MID = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM SUBSTR(@MID, 2)), -- here we get rid of equal sign and double quotes
    BonusAmount  = TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM NULLIF(@BonusAmount, '')),
    BonusAppliedDate = NULLIF(@BonusAppliedDate, ''),
    PartnerPercentage = NULLIF(@PartnerPercentage, ''),
    PartnerShare = TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM NULLIF(@PartnerShare, '')),
    TotalPayment = TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM NULLIF(@TotalPayment, ''))
```

**Second** approach is to leverage `LINES STARTING BY` clause

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE table_name
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' STARTING BY '='
    IGNORE 1 LINES 
(MID, DBAName, PartnerID, PartnerName, SubPartnerID, SubPartnerName, ActiveMonths, @BonusAmount, BonusAppliedDate, PartnerPercentage, PartnerShare, @TotalPayment)
SET BonusAmount  = TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM NULLIF(@BonusAmount, '')),
    BonusAppliedDate = NULLIF(@BonusAppliedDate, ''),
    PartnerPercentage = NULLIF(@PartnerPercentage, ''),
    PartnerShare = TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM NULLIF(@PartnerShare, '')),
    TotalPayment = TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM NULLIF(@TotalPayment, ''))
```

---

Now if your target table schema looks something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name 
(
    MID BIGINT, 
    DBAName           VARCHAR(100),
    PartnerID         INT,
    PartnerName       VARCHAR(100),
    SubPartnerID      INT,
    SubPartnerName    VARCHAR(100),
    ActiveMonths      INT,
    BonusAmount       DECIMAL(19, 2),
    BonusAppliedDate  DATE,
    PartnerPercentage DECIMAL(3, 2),
    PartnerShare      DECIMAL(19, 2),
    TotalPayment      DECIMAL(19, 2)
);
```

Then after loading with either method here is what we get in the table

```
mysql> select * from table_name;
+---------------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
| MID           | DBAName  | PartnerID | PartnerName | SubPartnerID | SubPartnerName | ActiveMonths | BonusAmount | BonusAppliedDate | PartnerPercentage | PartnerShare | TotalPayment |
+---------------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
| 8788014065741 | company2 |      7968 | me          |        11839 | Joe Blow       |            0 |       50.00 | NULL             |              NULL |         NULL |       350.64 |
| 8788014065756 | company2 |      7968 | you         |        11839 | Joe Blow       |            0 |       50.00 | NULL             |              NULL |         NULL |       294.60 |
+---------------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: great answer, I used your first method.  Thanks for the help and extra detail behind the answer too!